# display image in a view

Tags: xpages

I am trying to learn the best way to create an xpage containing data from a notes view to provide something like an ebay items grid list. Where you have data items such as name, description, and a thumbnail image.

On the documents contained in the view there is a rich text field that contains the thumbnail image. What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: I think maybe your subject is wrong, maybe it should be "display images from a view"?

Comment: Oh my! If @ThomasAdrian is right then I have answered your question according to your title "display image in a view".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Notes view create a column which shows the name of attachment in column using formula `@AttachmentNames`. Then in your view control in XPage set the `var` property to, say, `rowData`. Then you can use this `rowData` variable to get the current document being shown in view. You can use the below code snippet of view column to show icon image attached in document as view icon.

```
<xp:viewColumn>
    <xp:this.facets>
        <xp:viewColumnHeader xp:key="header"></xp:viewColumnHeader>
    </xp:this.facets>
    <xp:this.iconSrc><![CDATA[#{javascript:rowData.getDocument().getUniversalID() + "/$FILE/" + rowData.getColumnValue("$1")}]]></xp:this.iconSrc>
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:""}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:viewColumn>
```

Modify the above code to use the programmatic name of column which displays the attachment names in `rowData.getColumnValue("$1")`.

One assumption here is that there is only one attachment per document. Also I don't know whether this is the best way, but it worked for my scenario.

Answer (score 2):

1. Put you document collection within a repeat
2. within the repeat put a panel with tagName "span", add a document data source and set the style to float:left
3. Put an image control within the panel and set the source to the document data e.g /0/unid/$File/filename